# Probability of a nonnegative submartingale converging to zero

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Suppose that $\{X_k\}$ is a nonnegative submartingale, and $\Pr(X_1 = 0) = 0$. Then could we conclude that $\Pr(\liminf X_k=0) = 0$? What about $\Pr(\lim X_k=0) = 0$?

Some background information: This question arises when analysing the convergence of some randomized algorithm, where $X_k$ is the "distance" of the iterate from some "bad situation"; the desire is to prove that the iterate can avoid the bad situation with probability one.

Comment: I do not understand why the question is regarded as "off-topic". I think the mathematical problem is stated clearly. The background context is probably not interesting to anybody at all, if not confusing, which is the reason why I did not put it here. I am also a mathematician and I understand that it is very important to identify the mathematical essence of your problem instead of distracting yourself/your audience by unnecessary details. As a forum on mathematics, we should focus more on mathematics rather than irrelevant engineering/technical details. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: let $\Omega=\{a,b\}$, $\mathcal{F}=2^\Omega$ and suppose that your filtration is $\mathcal{F}_1=\{\emptyset,\Omega\}$ and, for any $k\ge 2$, $\mathcal{F}_k=2^\Omega$.
Let $\mathbb{P}$ be given by $\mathbb{P}(\{a\})=\mathbb{P}(\{b\})=\frac{1}{2}$. 
Let $X_1\equiv 1$ and for $k\ge 2$ $X_k(a)=2$, $X_k(b)=0$. Then $(X_k)$ is a nonnegative converging martingale, with $\mathbb{P}(X_1=0)=0$, but as you can see
$$\mathbb{P}(\lim\inf X_k=0)=\mathbb{P}(\lim X_k=0)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, @Mizar. What if $\Pr(X_i=0)=0$ for each $i \ge 0$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Putting a little perturbation to @Mizar's example will yield an example for the new question. Thanks.